# I am trying to use Draft.js where I need to add inline image and text

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I am trying to add image and text in one line. But I am not able to do that.

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-pond-je3n1?file=/src/Media.js

I tried every way, I used custom blocks, wrapper blocks but I am not able to get the text and image in one line.

I even used slate.js but not able to do the same.
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-einstein-q8gsk?file=/src/SlateMediaEditor.jsx:3106-3308

I searched everywhere but I am not able to find anywhere a example to do inline things.

```
function mediaBlockRenderer(block) {
  if (block.getType() === "atomic") {
    return {
      component: Media,
      editable: true
    };
  }

  return null;
}
```

```
const Image = props => {
  return (
    <img
      style={{ width: 24, height: 14 }}
      width="14px"
      height="14px"
      src={props.src}
      style={styles.media}
    />
  );
};
```

```
const Media = props => {
  const entity = props.contentState.getEntity(props.block.getEntityAt(0));
  const { src } = entity.getData();
  const type = entity.getType();

  let media;
  if (type === "audio") {
    media = <Audio src={src} />;
  } else if (type === "image") {
    media = <Image src={src} />;
  } else if (type === "video") {
    media = <Video src={src} />;
  }

  return media;
};
```

I want to add text side by side of image, but whenever I am trying new text block is created in new line.

Comment: What's the actual problem? Give a [mre], *in the question*.

Comment: I am not able to add image and text in same line. I have given codesandbox link.

Comment: A code sandbox link is *not* a MRE.

Comment: have you tried to format the block with CSS like float ? I guess this is the easiest way. Other option could be to use an entity instead of a block and use a decorate to render the image.